# C read part of file into cache

Tags: c, file, file-io, cache-control

I have to do a program (for Linux) where there's an extremely large index file and I have to search and interpret the data from the file. Now the catch is, I'm only allowed to have x-bytes of the file cached at any time (determined by argument) so I have to remove certain data from the cache if it's not what I'm looking for.

If my understanding is correct, fopen (r) doesn't put anything in the cache, only when I call getc or fread(specifying size) does it get cached.

So my question is, lets say I use fread and read 100 bytes but after checking it, only 20 of the 100 bytes contains the data I need; how would I remove the useless 80 bytes from cache (or overwrite it) in order to read more from the file.

**EDIT** By caching I mean data stored in memory, which makes the problem easier

Comment: I suspect that you are somewhat confused. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "cache" in this case? Are you referring to the O/S cache, or to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fread`'s first argument is a pointer to a block of memory. So the way to go about this is to set that pointer to the stuff you want to over write. For example lets say you want to keep bytes 20-40 and overwrite everything else. You could either a) invoke `fread` on start with a length of 20 then invoke it again on `buffer[40]` with a size of 60. or b) You could start by defragmenting (ie copy the bytes you want to keep to the start) then invoke `fread` with a pointer to the next section.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to micromanage the cache? Secondly, what makes you think you can? No argument specified on the command line of your program can control what the cache manager does internally - it may decide to read an entire file into RAM, it may decide to read none of it, or it may decide to throw a party. Any control you have over it would use low-level APIs/syscalls and would not very granular.

Comment: It's what my professor has as one of the requirements for the assignment. I think it's dumb because I thought the whole point of the cache was to not notice it as long as you go through memory predictably

Comment: You need to go back to your Professor and ask him what *exactly* he means by "cache" in this case. Frankly, if he wants you to micro-manage the O/S cache, he's an idiot. And you can feel free to tell him I said so.

Comment: after rereading the directions more carefully, it's the data loaded into memory I'm constraint by, he just refers to it as caching and I suppose that's where my confusion came from. My mistake

Comment: Ahh! Now it makes much more sense. Do you have any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Yes I'm thinking of making a buffer of x-bytes big, extract relevant info and then read over the buffer but reduce its size by the size of the data I extracted EDIT: until I have all the relevant data I need

Comment: Good thinking. That's the correct way to go about it. Make sure to move things that you want to keep to the beginning of the buffer; this will (a) help simplify your code and (b) help to prevent "fragmentation" in your buffer, where you end up with many "small holes" in between the useful data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be confused about the requirements, or maybe the person who gave them to you.  You seem to be referring to the cache managed by the operating system, which there is no need for an application to ever have to worry about.  The operating system will make sure it doesn't grow too large automatically.

The other meaning of "cache" is the one you create yourself, the `char*` buffer or whatever you create to temporarily hold the data in memory while you process it.  This one should be fairly easy to manage yourself simply by not allocating too much memory for that buffer.

Answer (score -1):

To discard the read buffer of a file opened with fopen(), you can use fflush(). Also note that you can control the buffer size with setvbuf().

You should consider using open/read (instead of fopen/fread) if you must have exact control over buffering, though.

Comment: setvbuf is for the stream buffering done by the C library. Simiarly, fflush *only* operates on those buffers. They have nothing to do with the cache implemented by the O/S.

Comment: Yes, but the standard C library always does buffering (it has a default buffer size of BUFSIZ). If he wants control of the buffering, that's the way to do it.

Comment: He spoke about the cache but I guess it's theoretically possible that he meant the buffers maintained by the C standard libraries...